# BeautifulSoup return unexpected extra spaces

Tags: python, html, text, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab some text from html documents with BeautifulSoup. In a very relavant case for me, it originates a strange and interesting result: after a certain point, the soup is full of extra spaces within the text (a space separates every letter from the following one). I tried to search the web in order to find a reason for that, but I met only some news about the opposite bug (no spaces at all).

Do you have some suggestion or hint on why it happens, and how to solve this problem?.

This is the very basic code that i created:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.beppegrillo.it")
prova = html.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(prova)
print soup
```

And this is a line taken from the results, the line where this problem start to appear:

> value=\"Giuseppe labbate ogm? non vorremmo nuovi uccelli chiamati lontre\"><input onmouseover=\"Tip('<cen t e r   c l a s s = \ \ ' t i t l e _ v i d e o \ \ ' > < b > G i u s e p p e   l a b b a t e   o g m ?   n o n   v o r r e m m o   n u o v i   u c c e l l i   c h i a m a t i   l o n t r e <

Comment: Why are you printing `ultrasoup`? Shouldn't it be `soup`?

Comment: Same problem here with an other website. I'm still trying to figure out whether this is a problem with BeautifulSoup or the underlying lxml. The software runs without problems on a 32bit-Python and fails with 64bit.

Comment: I apologize for 'ultrasoup', just a small error. Of course, the right code was 'print soup'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe this is a bug with Lxml's HTML parser. 
Try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen ("http://www.beppegrillo.it")
prova = html.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(prova.replace('ISO-8859-1', 'utf-8'))
print soup
```

Which is a workaround for the problem. 
I believe the issue was fixed in lxml 3.0 alpha 2 and lxml 2.3.6, so it could be worth checking whether you need to upgrade to a newer version.

If you want more info on the bug it was initially filed here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/972466

Hope this helps,

Hayden

Comment: This is working perfectly, thanks. Can I ask you what replace is replacing in this case? A further question: beautifulsoup always adopt lxml html parser? If not, why i am using it, and how can i control which parser i adopt? I think these might appear as dummy questions, but i am a beginner in html parsing

Answer (score 9):

You can specify the parser as `html.parser`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(prova, 'html.parser')
```

Also you can specify the `html5` parser:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(prova, 'html5')
```

Haven't installed the `html5` parser yet? Install it from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-html5lib
```

The `xml` parser may be used (`soup = BeautifulSoup(prova, 'xml')`) but you may see some differences in [multi-valued attributes](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes) like `class="foo bar"`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, it works after change the encoding

```py
                with open(src, "r", encoding="UTF-16") as file:
                    html = file.read()
                    html = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Comment: Where does OP uses a file?

Comment: @SvenEberth Updated the answer