# Scraping site with strange html

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Somebody know why the html of this [site](https://rs.olx.com.br/regioes-de-porto-alegre-torres-e-santa-cruz-do-sul/imoveis/casa-em-canoas-no-bairro-igara-iii-457256663) have with this spaces between the words?

Is possible clean that for use BeautifulSoup?

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859832/beautifulsoup-return-unexpected-extra-spaces) Q&A indicates that it may be an issue with your parser/version. Are you up-to-date?

Comment: I felt it is normal and you can clean it by using strip split etc.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't seem to have that problem... Is your code significantly different from this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://rs.olx.com.br/regioes-de-porto-alegre-torres-e-santa-cruz-do-sul/imoveis/casa-em-canoas-no-bairro-igara-iii-457256663'
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: i having use lxml

Comment: the html extracted is'n the html of page in chrome