# While scraping I cannot access the full html body

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape headlines from the main Spanish newspaper using BeautifulSoup in python. 
While doing it in different sites I found the following common pattern. 
When I print the scraped HTML code it looks good at the top of it, but at some points starts inserting three spaces between every character. So I can't work with it.

I have tried in a few sites (such as https://www.marca.com/) and the issue keeps happening.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get("https://www.elmundo.es/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
soup
```

I expect to see the full plain HTML code, but it appears with the spaces between characters.

Comment: What exactly do you expect as output? Mine started with `<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="es">\n<head>\n<meta`

Comment: Yes, it is the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859832/beautifulsoup-return-unexpected-extra-spaces

Comment: I solved it by chaging lxml to html5 as shown below: 
`soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html5')`